# jPopupMenu at the position of Hyperlink in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, jeditorpane, jpopupmenu

I am implementing an editor in Swing. It shows plain text with hyperlinks. The problem statement is that when a user clicks on a hyperlink, a popup menu must appear at the mouse position or just below the hyperlink text. User can select the option from the menu and the text of hyperlink will be updated to the text in the option user selected. Moreover, after selecting the option, the menu disappears.

I am trying it on both jTextPane and jEditor pane. I used hyperlinkUpdate listener to display popup menu, but it always appears at the top left corner of the GUI.
Moreover, I could not find how to update the text of the hyperlink.

Here is the code of hyperlinkUpdate event:

```
private void jEditorPane1HyperlinkUpdate(javax.swing.event.HyperlinkEvent evt) {                                             
    if(evt.getEventType() == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED){
    System.out.println(evt.getDescription());
    jPopupMenu1.setAlignmentX(jEditorPane1.getMousePosition().x);
    jPopupMenu1.setAlignmentY(jEditorPane1.getMousePosition().y);
    jPopupMenu1.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Someone kindly guide me in this matter.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem, this will reduce the guess work and produce better response

Comment: @MadProgrammer I have added some code in the question. Rite now I have just made a sample popupmenu with one menuItem to check my working.

Comment: Don't use `getMousePosition`, you should be trying to find the location that the associated `Element` resides within the Editor's view

Comment: @MadProgrammer...okay, lemme try it that way

Comment: @MadProgrammer I try evt.getSourceElement() but this thing also has no coordinates.

Comment: Yep, you'll need to convert the information from the element into view coordinates

Comment: @MadProgrammer Hi, do you happen to know how ?

Comment: Oh it seems to be possible with `jeditorpane.modelToView2D(hle.getSourceElement().getStartOffset())`

Answer (score 1):

The call should be like this

```
        JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
        popup.add("Item 1");
        popup.add("Item 2");
        popup.show(mouseEvent.getComponent(),mouseEvent.getX(),mouseEvent.getY());
```

See an example here
http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Java/Q_20143329.html

Comment: actually I am using hyperlink event so mouse event wont work.

Comment: Ok. Then you have source element. Use the element's start/end offset and convert it to X, Y coordinates useing modelToView(). The componnet to be used is the JEditorPane instance

Comment: I user 'popup.show(jEditorPane1, jEditorPane1.getMousePosition().x, jEditorPane1.getMousePosition().y);' in your code and it worked somehow. Will now to link event to item.

Comment: It's better to use modelToView method of jEditorPane1 passing offset of the element to get correct coordinates of the hyperlink

Comment: I have done it like this 
'Rectangle rec = jEditorPane1.modelToView(evt.getSourceElement().getStartOffset());
popup.show(jEditorPane1, rec.x, rec.y);'
but it gives popup menu only when clicked at the start of the hyperlink.
P.S. It has nothing to do with startOffset, same happents on 'getEndOffest()'

Comment: @JaveriaHabib Thank you very much, more precisely I used `jEditorPane.modelToView2D(it.sourceElement.startOffset).y.toInt()` (in kotlin).